# AWS loadbalancer + Nginx + gunicorn - how to use ssl

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx

Im trying to use docker-machine to create ec2 instances with the stack nginx+gunicorn+django. I have an internet-facing Application Load balancer with two target groups (green/blue) to prevent any downtime in new deployment (new deployments gets deployed to the unused group, and the load balancer group is changed when everything checks out)

Everything works perfect with port 80, but when I try to add a listener for port 443 with a Amazon Issued Cert for that domain, I can't get it to work. Do I need to obtain certs from inside Nginx also? Do I need Nginx to listen to port 443? Targets?

Loadbalancer:

```
+------------+-----------------------------+----------------+
| Listener ID|            Rules.           | SSL Certificate|
+------------+-----------------------------+----------------+
| HTTP: 80   | Default: forwarding to blue.| N/A.           |
+------------+-----------------------------+----------------+
| HTTPS: 443 | Default: forwarding to blue.|Default: (ACM). |
+------------+-----------------------------+----------------+
```

Targets:

```
+------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+---------------+
|    Name    |     Port     |   Protocol   |  Target type | Load Balancer |
+------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+---------------+
| Blue       | 80           | HTTP         | instance     | loadbalancer  |
+------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+---------------+
| Green      | 80           | HTTP         | instance     |               |
+------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+---------------+
```

My Nginx conf:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
  include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type  application/octet-stream;

  log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

  access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

  sendfile        on;
  #tcp_nopush     on;

  keepalive_timeout  65;

  upstream app {
    server django:5000;
  }

  server {
    listen 80;
    charset utf-8;

    location = /favicon.ico {
        return 204;
        access_log     off;
        log_not_found  off;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri @proxy_to_app;
    }

    # django app
     location @proxy_to_app {
        proxy_redirect     off;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        proxy_pass http://app;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: if it's Elastic Load Balancer, you should install SSL cert on it.

Comment: Yes, the loadbalancer has an Amazon Issued SSL cert installed and in use on port listener for 443.

Comment: What exact error, are you seeing?. Where do you see traffic is being stopped?. At ALB side or Nginx level?. You can have ALB listen on 443 and do SSL termination and perform backend Nginx on 80.

Comment: Wow, stupid mistake! My security group used by docker-machine, does not automatically allow for port 443, since it is not specified in docker-compose. Added the rule, and now everything works!

Comment: ohh. glad. It's resolved!!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing my own answer if any one else encounter this problem.

The security-group used to create the Ec2 instance needs to have incoming port 443 open. If your docker-compose file does not expose port 443, it will not automatically add the port as open on the security-group. You can manual open the port in the aws console for Ec2 under network & security.

Comment: `gunicorn` listens on port 800 by default. so how do you set gunicon to listen on ssl?

Comment: Not a good idea to expose gunicorn directly to the internet. Use a reverse proxy in front of it, like nginx or traefik.

Comment: I understand however I have got apache to listen to port 443 and proxy to gunicorn on port 8000 now. but I can't seem to get it to work via elastic beanstalk